# AccessControlException createClassLoader

Tags: java, applet, classloader

I'm using custom class loader and the Microsoft JDBC driver in my applet. When my class loader calls super() in the body of its constructor (creates new instance of class loader) I get

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")

Now, I have tried running applet through jnlp

```
<param name="jnlp_href" value="permissions.jnlp">
```

with

```
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
```

...but the browser just freezes to death.

Later, I have signed the JAR containing my applet, and I still get

> java.security.AccessControlException

Is there a solution to this? Please, don't suggest

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

It's a heavy, not user-friendly solution.